# Why are notifications displayed on my lockscreen even though visibility is set to VISIBILITY_PRIVATE or VISIBILITY_SECRET?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, lockscreen

I am trying to get android notifications to work the way they are supposed to, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification).

I have spent quite a long time on this and am aware of common pitfalls. Still, I have a few issues, one of them being that notifications are always displayed on my lock screen, whatever the visibility I specify on the channel and notification.

I do uninstall and re-install the app between each try, whenever I change something on the channel.

I am getting my notification manager with `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)`

I am setting lock screen visibility *before* creating the channel:
`notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)`

I am also setting visibility on each notification

```
NotificationCompat
.Builder(context, channelId)
.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
// [...]
.build();
```

I used to call `.setPublicVersion(publicSummaryNotificationBuilder.build())`, where publicSummaryNotificationBuilder would build a similar notification hiding private information. I don't do it anymore: anyway the whole notifications with all details are displayed on the lock screen regardless of a public version being available or not.

I am testing on a Huawei device using EMUI, based on Android 9 Pie I (API 28). I would be tempted to blame the OS (EMUI) for this strange behavior, but other apps seem to successfully output notification with stripped private content on the lock screen.

Any idea?